# How to add images in js

Tags: javascript, image, magento2.4.1

How to include images in js,

My code :

```
if (firstStore.address && firstStore.state && firstStore.zip && firstStore.store_hours_weekdays && firstStore.store_hours_weekend_days && firstStore.phone ) {

    homeAddress = '<div class="homepage-store">' + firstStore.address + ',' + firstStore.state + ' ,' + firstStore.zip + '<br><br> ' <<add image here>> + firstStore.store_hours_weekdays +' <br> ' +firstStore.store_hours_weekend_days+ ' <br><br> ' <<add image here >> + firstStore.phone + '</div>';

}
```

Comment: Try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124371/how-to-get-url-for-static-image-file-in-magento2-javascript-files